# Unable to execute Sas INTCK in macro

Tags: date, sas, macros

I'm running the following macro:

```
%macro diff(yymm);

%let date1=%sysfunc(inputn(strip(putn(&yymm.,yymmn6.))||'01',yymmdd10.));
%let date2=%sysfunc(inputn(strip(putn(201811,yymmn6.))||'01',yymmdd10.));

%let j=%sysfunc(intck(month,&date1.,&date2.));
%put &date1. &date2. &j.;
%mend;
%diff(201807);
%diff(201808);
```

Basically to find the difference in months from Nov'18 to whichever date I pass as argument to this macro. I'm not sure where am I going wrong, but I get this following error:

```
Argument 1 to function INPUTN referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is out of range.
NOTE: Mathematical operations could not be performed during %SYSFUNC function execution. The result of the operations have been set 
      to a missing value.
```

Can somebody please help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating the string to date conversion. You've already got the string in format YYMMN6., you just need to get the actual date value from that string.

```
%macro diff(yymm);
    %let date1 = %sysfunc(inputn(&yymm, yymmn6.));
    %let date2 = %sysfunc(inputn(201811, yymmn6.));

    %let j=%sysfunc(intck(month,&date1.,&date2.));
    %put &date1. &date2. &j.;
%mend;

%diff(201807);
%diff(201808);
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, but my &date1. reads as 21366 when it should be reading as 201807.

Comment: The `intck` function works on date values, which are numeric. 21366 is the numeric representation of July 1st, 2018. SAS tracks dates as the number of days since January 1st, 1960.

Comment: Is there a way for me to make it read it as it is? Given that I will need the output finally as 201807, 201808 etc

Comment: You mean you want `201807 201811 4` to be written to the log when you run `%diff(201807)`? If so, just change it to `%put &yymm. 201811 &j.`.

Comment: Yeah..but the thing is this is actually for a coding homework that has been assigned to me..and the instructor specifically wants to see the correct values of date1 and date2 :P

Comment: So this code is using `%sysfunc()` to call the `inputn()` function to convert a string that looks like YYYMM into an actual date.  I leave it to you to figure out how to convert the actual date value back to a string in YYYMM style.

Comment: @IndigoChild `%SYSFUNC()` takes two parameters, look into what the second parameter is.

Answer (score 3):

The YYMMN6. informat is not going to recognize `strip(` as a valid date value.  You cannot call functions in macro code without wrapping each function in the `%sysfunc()` macro function, they will just look like letters to the macro processor.

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
%macro diff(yymm);
  %put &yymm 201811 %sysfunc(intck(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&yymm, yymmn6.)),'01NOV2018'd));
%mend;
```

Result:

```
1104  %diff(201807);
201807 201811 4
1105  %diff(201808);
201808 201811 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates are consistently in YYYYMM format then, couldn't you simply use something like this:

```
%macro diff(yymm);

  %put %eval((%substr(&yymm, 1,4) - 2018)*12 + (%substr(&yymm, 5,2) - 11));

%mend;
```